# How to use jest and enzyme to test the function in a connected component?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I have a connected component, in which there is a method being called when the component is loaded. I tried many other methods such as exporting both the component and the connected component, using dive().instance() which gives me the error saying the `dive() is not a function`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };

    handleClick() {
        this.props.updateDetails();
    }

    samplefunc(){ `return a list of tags such as <Link /> or <li>` };

    render(
        return { 
           <div>
             <button>{this.handleClick()}</button>
             <div>this.samplefunc()</div>
           </div>
        };
    )
   
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatchEvent, ownProps) => {
    return {
        updateDetails: () => {
            dispatchEvent({
                type: "UPDATE",
                payload: {
                    id: "id"
                },
            });
        },
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

My test file is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { App } from '../App';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({});

describe("app", () => {
    let mountApp = mount(
         <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/path']}>
             <App 
                 store={store}
             />
         </MemoryRouter>
    )
    
    let spySamplefn;
    beforeEach(() => {
        spySamplefn = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "samplefunc");
    });

    it("calles the sample func", () => {
        expect(spySamplefn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })

})
```

But I get the error of

```
Cannot spy the samplefunc property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

I think this is some standard problem for the beginners on front-end testing like me.

### Update

I change to spyOn the instance of the mocked class by and spyOn the function of that instance, then the test passes. But I don't quite get the reason why it passes, any explanation is appreciated.

```
describe('when the message is loaded', () => {
        let spySamplefn;

        const MyApp = mountApp().find(App);
        const instance = MyApp.instance();

        beforeEach(() => {
            spySamplefn = jest.spyOn(instance, "samplefunc");
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            spySamplefn.mockClear();
        });

        it('calls the renderCategoryList method', () => {
            instance.samplefunc();
            expect(spySamplefn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
        
    });
```

Comment: You can just use [ownProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) and not mock the store itself but mock that specific function and spy on it

Comment: @vsync Could you please give an example for this?

Comment: You shouldn't dispatch events directly from the component but instead import your ***action creators*** and use them as-is, in your `mapDispatchToProps` function's returned *object*

Answer (score 1):

Your App is the connected component that wrap your App component therefore it's undefined.
Try to create wrapper and find your component instance

```
const wrapper = mount(<App/>);
const MyApp = wrapper.find('APP'))
const instance = MyApp.instance();

    it("calles the sample func", () => {
        expect(instance.samplefn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

Comment: This way I get the error of `Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`, I think the `spyOn` method is needed.

Comment: After I combined your method with a `spyOn` method, I get the test passed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you should [mock a constructor](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) of your component. But in this case if you need to use other methods from that component you should mock them as well:

```
// mock constructor only (it's enough just to load component)
jest.mock('../App', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => { // mock implementation });
});

// the same by other syntax
jest.mock('../App', () => {
    return function () { // mock implementation };
});

// mock class with other methods (it's needed if you call some methods after loading)
jest.mock('../App', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            samplefunc: jest.fn(() => { // mock implementation })
            render: jest.fn(() => { // mock implementation })
        };
    });
});
```